# c# Dictionary Extension Method FirstOrDefault not returning expected Value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to do the twoSum leetcode problem where :

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

So here is my method:

```
    static public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> numberAndComplement = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            int complement = target - (int)nums[i];
            if (numberAndComplement.ContainsValue(nums[i]))
            {
               int[] vs =  { numberAndComplement.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == complement).Key, i}; 
               return vs;
            }
            numberAndComplement.Add(i, complement);
        }
        return new int[] { 0, 0 };
```

When passing in [3,2,4],6 I would expect indices [1,2] to be the response but instead I'm getting [0,2] which makes no sense because it's not an off by one error. The way I'm using FirstOrDefault I should be getting 1 back and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Did you debug it?

Comment: Yes, complement == 4, and they only value in the dictionary with value == 4 is key == 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be wrong -if (numberAndComplement.ContainsValue(nums[i])) - need to be searching for the complement, since the number is already in i.

```
static public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> numberAndComplement = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        int complement = target - (int)nums[i];
        
        if (numberAndComplement.ContainsValue(complement))
        {
           int[] vs =  { numberAndComplement.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == complement).Key, i}; 
           return vs;
        }
        numberAndComplement.Add(i, nums[i]);
    }
    return new int[] { 0, 0 };
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're right, I must be tired. I just had to change the line to this: 

int[] vs =  { numberAndComplement.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == nums[i]).Key, i};

Answer (score 1):

This solution would also pass through:

```
public class Solution {
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        var indices = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        for (int index = 0; index < nums.Length; index++) {
            if (indices.ContainsKey(target - nums[index])) {
                return new int[] { indices[target - nums[index]], index };

            }

            if (!indices.ContainsKey(nums[index])) {
                indices.Add(nums[index], index);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

#### If you are preparing for [interviews](https://leetcode.com/problemset/top-interview-questions/?listId=wpwgkgt):

- We'd like to write [bug-free](https://www.codegrip.tech/productivity/tips-to-write-bug-free-code-during-interview/) and [clean](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-cleaner-code-during-onsite-interviews) codes based on standards and conventions (e.g., [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>[1](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html), [2](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eeno/coding/CCodingStandard.html)</sup>, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), [2](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)</sup>, [java](/questions/tagged/java)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), [2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)</sup>, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)</sup>, [python](/questions/tagged/python)<sup>[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)</sup>, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)</sup>, [go](/questions/tagged/go)<sup>[1](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments)</sup>, [rust](/questions/tagged/rust)<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/)</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the `numberAndComplement` Dictionary at all?  Compute the complement and use [Array.IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netcore-3.1) to directly see if the number you are looking for is present in the source array. Just make sure that the index returned is not the same as the current `i` value in your loop:

```
static public Tuple<int, int> TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        int complement = target - nums[i];
        int complementIndex = Array.IndexOf(nums, complement);
        if (complementIndex != -1 && complementIndex != i)
        {
            return new Tuple<int, int>(i, complementIndex);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I suppose for a large inputs, though, the Dictionary approach would speed things up in finding the complement.  This is a classic speed vs. memory problem...

Comment: Recent C# releases include native language support for tuples.  You don't need to use the `Tuple` or `ValueTuple` classes anymore.  Your function could be declared as `static public (int, int)  TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)` or even `static public (int arrayIndex, int complementIndex)  TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)`.  Then your return statement would be `return (i, complementIndex);`

Comment: Nice @Flydog57.  Thanks for the info.